# execute Javascript after window.open()

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I'm trying to open an html page using `window.open()`.

This works, however, the JavaScript on the HTML doc opened is not executed. I already checked my JavaScript code (and tested it when the html doc is directly opened) - so the mistake is not in the code.

Does anyone know, why the JavaScript on an HTML document created with `window.open()` is not executed ? I guess it's some security mechanism in the browser, is it possible to bypass it?

Here is the relevant code:

```js
var win = window.open("", "...");
let htmlCode = "<html>...<script> ...</script> </html>"; 
win.document.body.innerHTML = htmlCode;
```

(`htmlCode` is the response of an `XMLHttpRequest`, which is properly formatted html code).

The JavaScript not working is related to an onclick=function(...), where function is defined in `<script> ... </script>` later. The error message is that the function is not defined. I copied the exact same code into a new html document, the javascript is working there.

The web page opened by window.open() is an about:blank page

EDIT: I found the error, it was because I didn't define any url in window.open.

Comment: There's no such mechanism, but depending on the script, CORS issues might appear. We need to see the code to say something more accurate.

Comment: There's not much code after your edit, but make sure you've quoted the HTML string correctly and no errors can be seen in the console. Notice, that `<html>` is not allowed inside `body`.